# Sql Competitions

Tags: sql

Sorry to ask this kind of questions.

But I am eager to know some good sites where I can have the opportunity to have some sql competitions.

I found 1 
[TroyK's T-SQL Challenge](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/Q_20623909.html)

but it is not free.

I am looking for a free one.

And also C# programming competitions. One I found is [Code Chef](http://www.codechef.com/OCT09/)

I am Looking for some more.

Also, it should be for any ages!

Edited:

I liked [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/). It's nice

Also some TSQL programming challenge. Sql Server Central is good. But I am looking for more TSql programs

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that's a fair question. Who but SO users would know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For C#, [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) is a good one. It is not C# specific as answers can be submitted in any language. The challenges tend to be quite challenging as they are not just about solving the problem, but solving it quickly.

For SQL, [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/) publishes some PDF books called SQL Server Stumpers, as well as having SQL challenges every now and again.

Comment: I liked Project Euler. It's nice

Also some TSQL programming challenge. Sql Server Central is good. But I am looking for more TSql programs

Answer (score 2):

http://www.topcoder.com/ has regular programming competitions for multiple languages, c# included.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can do TroyK's challenge without registering for EE. Just see whether the desired result equals your result.

This way you cannot compete with others, though.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I haven't seen any SQL competitions but these are some of the resources we used in the FIU Programming Team:

http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8 was the official website my university programming team used to hone our skills. They accept answers in various languages, but the focus is more on your algorithms than your syntax.

For some softer stuff many FIU students used http://codingbat.com/ which also accepts a few different languages. Many of the problems on this site were simple and straightforward, the challenge came in trying to code them as fast as possible.